# Constrain a table such that each account can have one of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has these columns:

- `Id` (Primary Key): the id.
- `OwnerId` (Foreign Key): the id of the owner, which resides in another table.
- `TypeId` (Foreign Key): the type of thing this record represents. There are a finite number of types, which are represented in another table. This links to that table.
- `TypeCreatorId` (ForeignKey): the owner of the type represented by TypeId.
- `SourceId` (Foreign Key): this isn't important to this question.

I need to constrain this table such that for each Id, there can be only one of each TypeCreatorId. I hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a unique index on `OwnerId` and `TypeCreatorId`.

An example using MySQL (sorry, I don't use SQL Server):

```
alter table yourTable
    add unique index idx_newIndex(OwnerId, TypeCreatorId);
```

**Example.** I'll just put here what would happen with this new unique index:

```
OwnerId | TypeCreatorId
--------+--------------
   1    |    1
   1    |    2          -- This is Ok
   2    |    1          -- Ok too
   2    |    2          -- Ok again
   1    |    2          -- THIS WON'T BE ALLOWED because it would be a duplicate
```

Comment: Thank you very much! To confirm, this will allow multiple OwnerIds, but not multiple with the same OwnerIds **and** TypeCreatorIds, right?

Comment: @Jack I've edited my answer to include the `OwnerId` field (which is what I think you need), and added a little example.

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server, you have two options:

1. create a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`

   ```
   ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
   ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQ_Id_TypeCreator UNIQUE(Id, TypeCreatorId)
   ```
2. create a `UNIQUE INDEX`:

   ```
   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UIX_YourTable_ID_TypeCreator
   ON dbo.YourTable(Id, TypeCreatorId)
   ```

Basically, both things achieve the same thing - you cannot have two rows with the same `(Id, TypeCreatorId)` values.

Comment: Will this same method work if I replace Id with OwnerId, which isn't a primary key, though it is a foreign key to a primary key, so it might not matter.

Comment: @Jack: you can create a unique constraint or unique index on (almost) any column - it doesn't have to be a primary key column at all. Not supported are really large columns - like `varbinary(max)` or such.